# What to do when a tag is technically right, but its description serves a different concept?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently I saw this quesiton: [CCMenu misplaced under iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19438939/555690). One of its tags is [ccmenu](/questions/tagged/ccmenu).

`CCMenu` is a class of the cocos2d-iphone framework, so the use of this tag is fine in that question.

However, if you hover over this tag there, the description is the following;

> CCMenu displays the project status of CruiseControl continuous
>   integration servers as an item in the Mac OS X menu bar. Or in other
>   words, CCMenu is to OS X what CCTray is to Windows.

Which is most definitely NOT referring to the cocos2d-iphone class I mentioned.

What to do in this kind of situation? The use of this tag is good, because the question is about `CCMenu`, but the official tag is referring to something else.

Comment: Then it *isn't* the right tag, because it's not in line with what the tag description says.  It's that simple.

Comment: @Servy: Well, that's ridiculous, because [ALL questions tagged with CCMenu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ccmenu?page=1&sort=newest&pagesize=15) actually refer to cocos2d-iphone.

Comment: Add a `for questions about Cocos2D use [other-tag-name]` note to the tag description.

Answer (score 4):

Couple ideas:

1. [Suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/86675) an alternate meaning of [ccmenu](/questions/tagged/ccmenu). It'll go through the tag review process.
2. Tag it with the [ccmenuitem](/questions/tagged/ccmenuitem) tag. The description of that tag seems more in line with what you were talking about.

On that note, may I also suggest that [ccmenuitem](/questions/tagged/ccmenuitem) becomes a synonym of [ccmenu](/questions/tagged/ccmenu) (given that the wiki changes for CCMenu). They seem to be related.